# Invalid route in a Laravel search form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-form

Hi i'm following a tutorial bout how to set a search form but I'm getting a `route` error (`NotFoundHttpException`).

form

```
   {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET' ,'url' => 'search', 'class'=>'form-group main-form', 'id'=>'search-form', 'role'=>'form']) !!}
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
      <input class="form-group main-form" id="q_objname_en_cont" name="searchKey"  placeholder='Search by Job title' required="required" style="height:40px;width:60%" type="search">
      <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Search">
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Route

```
//Search route(get)
Route::get('search/{searchkey}', 'EmploiController@search')->where('searchkey', '[A-Za-z]+')->name('search');
```

url (browser)

```
http://localhost:8000/search?_token=LJpgN3AwCFoDElOkFsSOX8BBLU1IFOzMvUYiokQj&utf8=%E2%9C%93&searchKey=quia
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your route to this. You don't need the second part of url when you're passing the search parameters as the query string.

```
Route::get('search', 'EmploiController@search')->name('search');
```

Change your form to this. You don't need to send the csrf token when you're using form GET method.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET' ,'url' => 'search', 'class'=>'form-group main-form', 'id'=>'search-form', 'role'=>'form']) !!}
<input class="form-group main-form" id="q_objname_en_cont" name="searchKey"  placeholder='Search by Job title' required="required" style="height:40px;width:60%" type="search">
<input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Search">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I've also removed the unwanted input `<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">`. Add it back if it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is wrong with the tutorial you're following, there are not security concerns, and certainly, that is not the proper way to implement a search in Laravel, you are exposing your csrf_token to the world in every request to that route.

My advice for you is to read better resources and take a deep dive into the docs.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/search-option-in-laravel-5?page=1